# how to create a new QImage from an array of floats

Tags: image, qt

I have an array of floats that represents an Image.(column first).
I want to show the image on a QGraphicsSecene as a QPixmap. In order to do that I tried to create anew image from my array with the QImage constructor - QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format ).
I first created a new unsigned char and casted every value from my original array to new unsigned char one, and then tried to create a new image with the following code:

```
unsigned char * data = new unsigned char[fres.length()];
for (int i =0; i < fres.length();i++)
    data[i] = char(fres.dataPtr()[i]);

bcg = new QImage(data,fres.cols(),fres.rows(),1,QImage::Format_Mono);
```

The problem is when I try to access the information in the following way:

bcg->pixel(i,j);

I get only the value 12345.
How can I create a viewable image from my array.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the float -> uchar conversion?

Comment: And what does the original data represent?  Is each float 0..1 representing black..white?  Are there colour channels, or is it just grayscale?

Comment: No need to create the QImage on the heap, btw. It's implicitely shared (copy-on-write).

Comment: The float array represents a grayscale Image, which means that each float is in the range [0...1], where zero is black and 1 is white.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems here.

One, casting a `float` to a `char` simply rounds the `float`, so 0.3 may be rounded to 0 and 0.9 may be rounded to `1`.  For a range of 0..1, the `char` will only contain 0 or 1.

To give the char the full range, use a multiply:

```
data[i] = (unsigned char)(fres.dataPtr()[i] * 255);
```

(Also, your cast was incorrect.)

The other problem is that your `QImage::Format` is incorrect; `Format_Mono` expects 1BPP *bitpacked* data, not 8BPP as you're expecting.  There are two ways to fix this issue:

```
// Build a colour table of grayscale
QByteArray data(fres.length());

for (int i = 0; i < fres.length(); ++i) {
    data[i] = (unsigned char)(fres.dataPtr()[i] * 255);
}

QVector<QRgb> grayscale;

for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    grayscale.append(qRgb(i, i, i));
}

QImage image(data.constData(), fres.cols(), fres.rows(), QImage::Format_Index8);
image.setColorTable(grayscale);
```

```
// Use RGBA directly
QByteArray data(fres.length() * 4);

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fres.length(); ++i, j += 4) {
    data[j] = data[j + 1] = data[j + 2] =         // R, G, B
        (unsigned char)(fres.dataPtr()[i] * 255);

    data[j + 4] = ~0;       // Alpha
}

QImage image(data.constData(), fres.cols(), fres.rows(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
```

Comment: HI,
thanks for the reply but, your second reply does not compile.
there is no constructor for QImage that receives a QByteArray.
So I've changed it to the following:

    unsigned char * c_data = new unsigned char[fres.length() * 4];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fres.length(); ++i, j += 4) {
      c_data[j] = c_data[j + 1] = c_data[j + 2] =(unsigned char)(fres.dataPtr()[i] * 255);
    c_data[j + 4] = ~0;
    }
QImage image(c_data, fres.cols(), fres.rows(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
And Still the image does not display properly.(all is black and not all the pixel values are 0).

Comment: @boaz shor, Sorry about it not compiling; calling `.constData()` on `data` should fix that.  I'm not sure what else could be the problem; have you tried the indexed (grayscale) version?